# Docusign and Salesforce1, Cannot proceed to Edit Envelope Screen

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi

A client uses Docusign with their Salesforce org, and desires to enable it for a custom object in Salesforce1. This scenario doesn't appear to be directly supported by Docusign.

As a workaround, I have created a custom publisher action that takes information from the custom object record and uses it to call /apex/dsfs__DocuSign_CreateEnvelope. In Salesforce1, when you click the publisher button it makes the call, and delivers you through to /apex/dsfs__docusign_editenvelope. But unfortunately, no interface appears, just a blank gray screen.

Does anyone have experience with this? Is Docusign's edit envelope screen using some kind of scripting that makes it incompatible with Salesforce1?